# Somar todos os registros de um campo INT no PHP e exibi-lo

Tags: php, mysql

Bom, basicamente preciso somar todos os meus registros do meu campo **`valor`** da minha tabela **`contas`** que está como `INT` no banco, o problema é que o resultado está dando "**0,01**", aonde estou errando?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> *Dividido por 100 para a conversão de centavos para reais.*

```
$resultado_total = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT sum(valor) FROM contas WHERE mes ='JANEIRO' ");
$linhas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_total);

$total_dividido = $linhas / 100;

$html .= '<td class = "total">TOTAL GASTO EM JANEIRO: '.number_format($total_dividido, 2, ',', '.')."</td>";
```

Comment: Olá, você está calculando o total gasto em janeiro com o número total de linhas, como está usando sum, a query retorna sempre uma linha. 1 / 100 = 0,01. Você tem que pegar o retorno do select para calcular o valor que precisa. Por favor dê uma olhada nesse exemplo da w3schools : https://tryphp.w3schools.com/showphpfile.php?filename=demo_db_select_oo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não está funcionando pois a **mysqli_num_rows** retorna apenas a quantidade total de linhas da sua consulta. No seu caso, está retornando **1** que dividido por 100 = 0,01.

Você precisa retornar o registro buscado, que no seu caso é uma soma, e armazenar o produto da soma na variável para depois dividi-la.

```
<?php
    //prepara query - usei um alias para facilitar o retorno (as total)
    $resultado_total = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT sum(valor) as total FROM contas WHERE mes ='JANEIRO' ");
    //transforma em objeto
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_object($resultado_total);
    //valor
    $valor = $resultado->total;
    $html .= '<td class = "total">TOTAL GASTO EM JANEIRO: '.number_format($valor , 2, ',', '.')."</td>";

?>
```